# Why i can not send email in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm try to send email with sql server ,for that purpose config with this way smtp:

> Outgoing mail server(SMTP)
>   ___________________________________ E-mail address:myEmail@gmail.com DisplayName:behzad ServerName:smtp.gmail.com PortNumber:587
>   Enable:This server requeires a secure connection (SSL)
>   ____________________________________ SMTP Authentication - Basic Authentication UserName:myEmail@gmail.com Password:my Email Password

But when try to send simple mail get this error:
 The mail could

> not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure.
>   (Sending Mail using Account 2 (2017-04-05T10:57:35). Exception
>   Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (The SMTP server requires a
>   secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server
>   response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at).
>   
>   read any help on internet and enable two step verification gmail and...
>   
>   but so get that error.How can i solve that problem?thanks.

Comment: When configuring SQL Server Database email there is an option `This server requires a secure connection (SSL): Checked ON`. Did you have this checked?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos yes i checked that

Comment: Have you used `Basic` or `Anonymous` authentication during configuration?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Set to Basic Authentication

Comment: Try port 465 for SSL.

Comment: What have you typed as the name of the `SMTP` server?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos smtp.gmail.com

Comment: @Datendenker That's it I think! Port 587 is for `TLS` (see [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)).

Comment: @Datendenker change to 465 port but so get this error: (Sending Mail using Account 2 (2017-04-05T11:29:27). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Failure sending mail.).

Comment: Are you using a proxy to connect to the outside world?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos no i dont use proxy my friend

Comment: Perhaps this may help: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en